# How to find spatial frequencies in fft of an image

Tags: image, transform, fft

I apply fft2 in MatLab to an aerial photo image. I get amplitudes of some spatial frequencies. But what are those frequencies? How to find them if I know number of pixels on the image and the pixel size in meters (size of the area of the object corresponding to one pixel)? 
Thank you.